# Split time into equal intervals in Java

Tags: java

Have a start time and end time that has to be split into equal interval.

E.g.

**Start Time:** 10AM,
**End Time:** 14PM,
**Split Time:** 30 minutes

The output has to be something like this -

::::**Output** :::

[{time:"10:00"},{time:"10:30"},{time:"11:00"},{time:"11:30"},{time:"12:00"},{time:"12:30"},{time:"13:00"},{time:"13:30"},{time:"14:00"}]

Thanks everyone in advance.

Comment: What would you do if there was a stub left over? i.e. imagine the end time is 14.15pm?

Comment: What do you think of a for loop? Is it so difficult? `for(int time = 10*60; time < 14*60; time+=30) {}`. You can ask a question if you do not understand something but you must try something and show it.

Comment: You could use the new Time API in Java 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, convert hours to minutes.

```
10AM = 10 * 60 minutes
2PM or 14h = 14 * 60 minutes
```

Then, in order to convert minutes back to hours :

```
minutes / 60 gives the number of hours
minutes % 60 gives the number of the minutes in the last hour.
```

If you want to display hours/minutes always on 2 digits, and eventually pad with a leading zero, use :

```
String result = String.format("%02d", minutes/60);
```

(`2` indicates that you want 2 digits and `0` indicates that you pad with zeros)

That said, there are 2 ways of going from `10*60` to `14*60` with steps of `30 minutes` :

**The most intuitive** : the while loop

```
public static void interval(int begin, int end, int interval) {
  int time = begin;
  while (time <= end) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%02d:%02d", time / 60, time % 60));
    time += interval;
  }
}
```

But I don't like `while` loops. If you do it wrong (or if the input data are wrong), it ends in infinite loops.

**The other way** : as you know the begin, the end and the step, use a `for` loop :

```
public static void interval2(int begin, int end, int interval) {
  for (int time = begin; time <= end; time += interval) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%02d:%02d", time / 60, time % 60));
  }
}
```

**Test** :

```
interval2(10 * 60, 14 * 60, 30);
```

**Result** :

```
10:00
10:30
11:00
11:30
12:00
12:30
13:00
13:30
14:00
```

Comment: Arnaud Denoyelle, This is what I was looking for. I'm new in Java. Thanks for the detailed explanation.